# SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer: \"[object Object]\"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use .create in a model and the following exception is returned:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer: \"[object Object]\"
```

All integer fields in PostgreSQL referring to the table are below:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cliente (
    cd_clientefv bigserial NOT NULL,
    cd_cliente int4 NULL,
    cd_empresa int4 NOT NULL,
    cd_cidadeibge int4 NOT NULL,
    cd_pais int4 NOT NULL,
    cd_regiaovendafv int8 NULL,
    cd_vendedor int8 NOT NULL,
    cd_estadoibge int4 NOT NULL,
);
```

My model:

```
const Cliente = database.define('cliente', {
    cd_clientefv: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true    
    },
    cd_cliente: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    cd_empresa: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,        
        allowNull: false  
    },
    cd_cidadeibge: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    cd_pais: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    cd_regiaovendafv: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: true
    },
    cd_vendedor: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    cd_estadoibge: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

Body JSON:

```
[
    {
        "cd_cliente":8048,
        "cd_cidadeibge":5210406,
        "cd_pais":1058,
        "cd_regiaovenda":14,
        "cd_estadoibge":52,
        "cd_empresa":5,
        "cd_vendedor":25
    }
]
```

Controller just try to:

```
await ClienteModel.create({
                    cd_cliente: cliente.cd_cliente,
                    cd_empresa: cd_empresa,
                    cd_cidadeibge: cliente.cd_cidadeibge,
                    cd_pais: cliente.cd_pais,
                    cd_regiaovendafv: cliente.cd_regiaovenda,
                    cd_vendedor: cdVendedor.cd_vendedor,
                    cd_estadoibge: cliente.cd_estadoibge
});
```

Apparently I have to pass an integer and an object is arriving, but that's not what happens!? When debugging what is actually present in each variable is an integer!

Note: there are several other tables that go through the same process, in none of them the same error is occurring; in 4 years of operation this exception never occurred, it started seemingly out of nowhere.

Please, is there something wrong or any additional information that could help with a possible resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your JSON body and Controller call examples :

```
[
  {
    "cd_cliente":8048,
    "cd_cidadeibge":5210406,
    "cd_pais":1058,
    "cd_regiaovenda":14,
    "cd_estadoibge":52,
    "cd_empresa":5,
    "cd_vendedor":25
  }
]

await ClienteModel.create({
        cd_cliente: cliente.cd_cliente,
        cd_empresa: cd_empresa,
        cd_cidadeibge: cliente.cd_cidadeibge,
        cd_pais: cliente.cd_pais,
        cd_regiaovendafv: cliente.cd_regiaovenda,
        cd_vendedor: cdVendedor.cd_vendedor,
        cd_estadoibge: cliente.cd_estadoibge
});
```

If I assume that

```
const cliente = {
  "cd_cliente":8048,
  "cd_cidadeibge":5210406,
  "cd_pais":1058,
  "cd_regiaovenda":14,
  "cd_estadoibge":52,
  "cd_empresa":5,
  "cd_vendedor":25
}
```

The error may be caused by `cd_empresa: cd_empresa` or `cd_vendedor: cdVendedor.cd_vendedor`

Did you check the type of those variables ? `cd_empresa` and `cdVendedor.cd_vendedor`

Comment: Yes, I did it just before .create call, all variables are integers.